# How to group by documents by week in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("568b650543712795bf864a45"),
    "companyId" : "55e2d7cfdc8f74d14f5c900f",
    "timeStamp" : ISODate("2014-12-03T18:30:00.000Z")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("568b650543712795bf864a49"),

    "companyId" : "55e2d7cfdc8f74d14f5c900f",
    "timeStamp" : ISODate("2014-12-04T18:30:00.000Z")
}
```

how to group by documents by week in mongodb. i need to get document grouped by last 7 weeks and week grouping should be on the basis of "timeStamp" field in the document.

Comment: have you tried aggregation framework ? Since you use 'group by' i assume that you come from sql (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) So in your case you need first to `$match` every document where `timeStamp` is gte  `new Date("2014-11-04")` (7 weeks ago from now) then `$group` by `timeStamp`

Answer (score 21):

You can achieve this by using the aggregate operation. There is $[week](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/week/#exp._S_week) aggregation operation in mongodb.

First determine the startDate using whatever programming language you use.

In following pipeline operation, counting the number of documents matching a week. You may do it on any field/type of aggregation you needed.

```
pipeline = [
    {
        $match: {
            timeStamp: {$gt: ISODate(startDate)},
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {$week: '$timeStamp'},
            documentCount: {$sum: 1}
        }
    }
];
db.mycollection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

For the above two documents you specified the result will be

```
{ "_id" : 48, "documentCount" : 2 }
```

The `_id` above says, 48th week, and there are two documents.

Go through the link $[week](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/week/#exp._S_week) to know how mongodb counts the week numbers.

Comment: If documents not present means it wont show anything. In that case how to show like  `{ "_id" : 48, "documentCount" : 0 }`

Comment: If your dataset spans same week numbers over more years, have a look at [`$isoWeekYear`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/isoWeekYear/), and use it in the `$group` step