# Issues aggregating mongo records by the last 7 days

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to count the occurences from each id_atendentes on the last 7 days/week.

I have the following query:

```
db.atendimentos.aggregate([
 {'$group' :
             {'_id' :
                 {'id_atendente':'$id_atendente', 'date':
                     { '$gte': new Date((new Date().getTime() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))) }
                }},
             'sum': {'$sum': 1} }
])
```

I thought that it would work, but it didn't.

I'm aware of the $week operator but I don't think that it does what I want to do.

I've got the following error: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.

I guess that it may be something with my 'date': { '$gte' }... part.

Hope to get some help, thanks!

Comment: Possible dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34610096/how-to-group-by-documents-by-week-in-mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand right, you would like to get last week documents, and then group them by the id_atendente, and count the amount each atendente occurred during the last week.

If that is the case, you first need to filter out documents from the last week with a `$match` stage, and then follow it with a `$group` stage to group by the atendente id.

I think the following code will do the job:

```
db.atendimentos.aggregate([
{
    '$match': {
        'date': {'$gte': new Date((new Date().getTime() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)))}
    },
},
{
    '$group':
        {
            '_id': "$id_atendente",
            'sum': {'$sum': 1}
        },
}
```

])

Comment: It seems to work, thank you, I'll accept your answer.